# How does the computer know that I am passing nearby?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

It strongly seems for me Gnome automatically goes out of blank-screen mode to asking me for password when after a pause I pass by near the computer.

Is it true?

If yes, how the system detects my presence: by webcam seeing me? by the microphone hearing my steps? both?

Or maybe, it is not a feature, but just microscopic movement of the mouse causes the login screen to appear?

Comment: My old fedora setup the screen used to come on by itself at night while asleep. You may be able to adjust the mouse sensitivity in linux? I know there is a command for that but cant remeber the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNOME has no such feature that detects when you are passing by the computer. I think your intuition is correct:

> Or maybe, it is not a feature, but just microscopic movement of the mouse causes the login screen to appear?

You can verify this by unplugging the mouse and walking by. Or if it's a built-in trackpad, disabling it in Settings.